# Code not reading the info from the json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to set up a command to view the amount of candy you have using the info stored in the json file. It doesn't seem to be reading the information correctly.

Here is the command file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const candyAmount = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./candyheld.json', {encoding:'utf8'}));
const { prefix } = require('../../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'candy',
    description: 'Displays the amount of candy the user has.',
    execute (message, args) {
        if (!candyAmount[message.author.id]) return message.channel.send(`You haven\'t started the event yet! Type ${prefix}trickortreat to start!`);

        const { candyStored } = candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored;
        message.channel.send(`You have ${candyStored} pieces of candy!`);
    },
};
```

and here is what the json file looks like when it has the info

```
{"ID":{"candyStored":5}}
```

I have removed the actual ID number and replaced it with just the word just for this moment. The actual number is in the code.

trickortreat command file

```
const fs = require('fs');

const candyAmount = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./candyheld.json', {encoding:'utf8'}));

module.exports = {
    name: 'trickortreat',
    description: 'Special Halloween command',
    execute(message, args) {
        
        if (!candyAmount[message.author.id]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id] = {
                candyStored: 5
            }
            
            fs.writeFile('./candyheld.json', JSON.stringify(candyAmount), err => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
            });
            
            return message.channel.send('For starting the event, you have been given 5 pieces of candy!');
        }
        
        // Stores a random number of candy from 1-3
        let candy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
        
        // Sets the possible messages to be received
        let trickortreatmessage = [
            'The scarecrow standing behind you jumps out at you and makes you drop all your candy!',
            `${message.guild.members.cache.random()} was nice enough to give you Candy! You got ${candy} pieces of candy!`,
            `Oh no you asked ${message.guild.members.cache.random()} for Candy and they decided to egg you instead!` 
        ]

        // Store one of the random messages
        const trickortreat = trickortreatmessage[Math.floor(Math.random() * trickortreatmessage.length)];

        if (trickortreat == trickortreatmessage[0]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored = 0;
        } else if (trickortreat == trickortreatmessage[1]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored = candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored + candy;
        }
        
        fs.writeFile('./candyheld.json', JSON.stringify(candyAmount), err => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        });

        message.channel.send(trickortreat);
    },
};
```

Comment: Did you try just requiring `candyheld.json` the same way you're doing with `config.json`?

Comment: What is it showing that is wrong?

Comment: @ericgio when done that way, I get "You have undefined pieces of candy!".

Comment: @kmoser it's not updating what it sees. The number in the file changes when it's supposed to but the code is not reading that. For instance, if there's no info there, it pops up saying to use /trickortreat to start. After doing that, the json file updates to show the info I pasted above. But when I use the /candy command again after that it still tells me that I have to use the command to start. If I start the bot with 5 pieces of candy and add 1, it still says there's only 5

Comment: @QuazArxx: That's because you're both destructuring and indexing into the object. Try either `const { candyStored } = candyAmount[message.author.id];` OR `const candyStored = candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored;`

Comment: @ericgio even with it that way the same issue is happening where it's just not updating. I had nothing in the file, did /candy, it said I needed to use /trickortreat, when I used that it updated and I got 5 candy, when I used the /candy command, it still said I needed to use /trickortreat to start which means it's still reading that my ID isn't there when it was updated to be there.

Comment: @QuazArxx: Please post the code for `/trickortreat`

Comment: @ericgio I added it to my original post although I'm not sure why you need it since that command works exactly as intended.

Comment: @QuazArxx: Your comments above suggest that `candyheld.json` is not updating properly. So it seems like the problem is in `/trickortreat`. `/candy` looks fine to me, other than the destructuring issue noted above.

Comment: candyheld.json is being updated as needed. I have checked every time something is taken away or added and it shows exactly what should be there. It’s /candy that’s not reading it correctly for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I've been adding some new things and trying to fix this issue and I got an update that will hopefully help figure this out. I made an "addcandy" command to add candy to specific users mentioned. When I use the command, and then use /candy, it reads it perfectly.

So I'm thinking @ericgio was right in that it has something to do with the "trickortreat" command. It adds the number fine but for some reason "candy" isn't reading that change. But it reads the change when I use "addcandy"

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out for anyone else having the same issue. I changed the "const candyAmount" to just be "require('../../candyheld.json') and did the same for my other files and it seems to read correctly now

old code line

```
const candyAmount = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./candyheld.json', {encoding:'utf8'}));
```

new code line

```
const candyAmount = require('../../candyheld.json');
```